# Hadoop CustomInputFormat NullPointerException

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I developed a custom non-splittable `InputFormat` for Hadoop, but I keep getting a `NullPointerException` when calling the record reader. Strangely, even when I update the code, rebuild, and add the jar with Hive's `ADD JAR` command, I'm not sure if the format get's updated because the log messages are always the same, even when I change it. Here are the relevant code snippets and messages:

## Error

```
2018-01-13 01:48:03,202 WARN  org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation: [HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-70]: PriviledgedActionException as:user (auth:SIMPLE) cause:org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: java.io.IOException: java.lang.NullPointerException
2018-01-13 01:48:03,202 WARN  org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftCLIService: [HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-70]: Error fetching results: 
org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: java.io.IOException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.getNextRowSet(SQLOperation.java:463)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.OperationManager.getOperationNextRowSet(OperationManager.java:294)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl.fetchResults(HiveSessionImpl.java:769)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy.invoke(HiveSessionProxy.java:78)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy.access$000(HiveSessionProxy.java:36)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy$1.run(HiveSessionProxy.java:63)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1917)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy.invoke(HiveSessionProxy.java:59)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30.fetchResults(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.CLIService.fetchResults(CLIService.java:462)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftCLIService.FetchResults(ThriftCLIService.java:694)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$FetchResults.getResult(TCLIService.java:1553)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$FetchResults.getResult(TCLIService.java:1538)
    at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:39)
    at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:39)
    at org.apache.hive.service.auth.TSetIpAddressProcessor.process(TSetIpAddressProcessor.java:56)
    at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:286)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator.getNextRow(FetchOperator.java:508)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator.pushRow(FetchOperator.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchTask.fetch(FetchTask.java:140)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.getResults(Driver.java:2069)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.getNextRowSet(SQLOperation.java:458)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator.getRecordReader(FetchOperator.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator.getNextRow(FetchOperator.java:446)
    ... 28 more
```

## CustomInputFormat

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.ObjectWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CompressionCodec;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CompressionCodecFactory;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileSplit;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InputSplit;
import java.io.DataInputStream;


import custom.util.Parser;

import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.RecordReader;


public class CustomInputFormat extends FileInputFormat<LongWritable, ObjectWritable> {
    public static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(CustomInputFormat.class);

    @Override
    public RecordReader<LongWritable, ObjectWritable> getRecordReader(InputSplit split, JobConf config, Reporter reporter)
            throws IOException {
        FileSplit fileSplit = (FileSplit)split;
        Path path = fileSplit.getPath();
        long start = 0L;
        long length = fileSplit.getLength();
        return initCustomRecordReader(path, start, length, reporter, config);


    }
     public static CustomRecordReader initCustomRecordReader(Path path, long start, long length, Reporter reporter,Configuration conf) throws IOException {
        FileSystem fs = path.getFileSystem(conf);
        FSDataInputStream baseStream = fs.open(path);
        DataInputStream stream = baseStream;

        CompressionCodecFactory compressionCodecs = new CompressionCodecFactory(conf);
        final CompressionCodec codec = compressionCodecs.getCodec(path);
        if (codec != null)
            stream = new DataInputStream(codec.createInputStream(stream));
        LOG.info("Reading FILE record: " + path.toUri().getPath());
        Parser parser = new Parser(stream);
        LOG.info("Initialized Parser");
        return new CustomRecordReader( baseStream, stream, reporter, start, length, parser);

     }


    @Override
    protected boolean isSplitable(FileSystem fs, Path filename) {
        return false;
}



}
```

## CustomRecordReader

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Seekable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.ObjectWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptContext;

import custom.util.Parser;

import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.RecordReader;


public class CustomRecordReader implements RecordReader<LongWritable, ObjectWritable> {

    TaskAttemptContext context;
    Seekable baseStream;
    DataInputStream stream;
    Reporter reporter;
    Parser parser;

    private LongWritable key = new LongWritable();
    private ObjectWritable value = new ObjectWritable();
    long packetCount = 0;
    long start, end;




    /**
     * @param context
     * @param baseStream
     * @param stream
     * @param reporter
     * @param parser
     */
    public CustomRecordReader(Seekable baseStream, DataInputStream stream, Reporter reporter, long start, long end,
            Parser parser) {
        this.baseStream = baseStream;
        this.stream = stream;
        this.reporter = reporter;
        this.parser = parser;
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean next(LongWritable key, ObjectWritable value) throws IOException {
        if (!this.parser.hasNext())
            return false;

        key.set(++packetCount);
        value.set(parser.next());

        reporter.setStatus("Read " + getPos() + " of " + end + " bytes");
        reporter.progress();

        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public LongWritable createKey() {
        return key;
    }
    @Override
    public ObjectWritable createValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public long getPos() throws IOException {
        return baseStream.getPos();
    }
    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        stream.close();

    }
    @Override
    public float getProgress() throws IOException {
        if (start == end)
            return 0;
        return Math.min(1.0f, (getPos() - start) / (float)(end - start));
    }




}
```

## Create Table operation

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE table1 (timestamp bigint,
protocol string,
src string,
dst int,
length int,
id bigint)
PARTITIONED BY (direction VARCHAR(64), minutes int)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'custom.CustomDeserializer'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'custom.CustomInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION '/user/user/input/raw';
```

## SerDe

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde.Constants;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.Deserializer;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeStats;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.ObjectInspector;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.ObjectInspectorFactory;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.typeinfo.TypeInfo;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.typeinfo.TypeInfoUtils;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.ObjectWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable;

import custom.util.Flow;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class CustomDeserializer implements Deserializer {

    ObjectInspector inspector;
    ArrayList<Object> row;
    int numColumns;
    List<String> columnNames;

    public void initialize(Configuration conf, Properties tbl) throws SerDeException {
        String columnNameProperty = tbl.getProperty(Constants.LIST_COLUMNS);
        columnNames = Arrays.asList(columnNameProperty.split(","));
        numColumns = columnNames.size();

        String columnTypeProperty = tbl.getProperty(Constants.LIST_COLUMN_TYPES);
        List<TypeInfo> columnTypes = TypeInfoUtils.getTypeInfosFromTypeString(columnTypeProperty);

        // Ensure we have the same number of column nameConstantss and types
        assert numColumns == columnTypes.size();

        List<ObjectInspector> inspectors = new ArrayList<ObjectInspector>(numColumns);
        row = new ArrayList<Object>(numColumns);
        for (int c = 0; c < numColumns; c++) {
            ObjectInspector oi = TypeInfoUtils.getStandardJavaObjectInspectorFromTypeInfo(columnTypes.get(c));
            inspectors.add(oi);
            row.add(null);
        }
        inspector = ObjectInspectorFactory.getStandardStructObjectInspector(columnNames, inspectors);

    }

    public Object deserialize(Writable w) throws SerDeException {
        ObjectWritable obj = (ObjectWritable)w;
        Flow flow = (Flow)obj.get();

        for (int i = 0; i < numColumns; i++) {
            String columName = columnNames.get(i);
            Object value = flow.get(columName);
            row.set(i, value);
        }
        return row;
    }

    public ObjectInspector getObjectInspector() throws SerDeException {
        return inspector;
    }

    public SerDeStats getSerDeStats() {
        return new SerDeStats();
    }

}
```

Can anyone help me by telling me what I did wrong, or at least if there's any way I can get the jar to update so I can at least get information with logs? Thank you.

Comment: Where is the corresponding  output format? What's your input format trying to get?

Comment: Since the NPE occurs in `org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator.getRecordReader`, I suspect your class is not being injected successfully/correctly.  Is there some configuration that tells Hadoop to include your custom reader? Can you show the configuration?

Comment: @JimGarrison I edited the code to include the create table statement. 

@cricket_007 , the output format is `OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'`

Comment: From the error, it reads like your SerDe is returning a null row

Comment: @cricket_007 Included the SerDe. It's just a simple serde that returns a row based on the given fields using a hashmap (`Flow extends Hashmap<String, Object>`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was wrong. It turns out, I think Hive caches some old jars that are used to build a table. Hive needs to first be restarted before debugging a different version of a jar with the same packages.